# how to keep number of files in a folder less than a limit

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

I'm trying to create a bash script to limit the number of files to a limit of 50000. I want to  run the bash script on crontab every 5 min so it can keep deleting the old files when the number of files go beyond the limit. I have written code, but it doesnt work as intended. It deleted all files instead of just the old ones. I intended to delete the last element until the number of files goes below the limit. Is there an easier way to do this process?

```
LIMIT=50000

NUMBER=$(find /mnt/capture/PPO/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" wc -l)

if [[ $NUMBER -gt $LIMIT ]]  #if number greater than limit
then

FILES=$(find /mnt/capture/PPO/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap")


for f in "${FILES[@]}"

 do

rm $FILES[$NUMBER-$f]
done
 #delete the originals
fi
```

Comment: You told a problem and you gave the code that solves the problem. What is your question?

Comment: Well it doesnt solve the problem. It just keeps deleting all files, thats not what I intended.

Comment: So why don't you write the real problem/what you really want? (In the question, not in a comment.)

Comment: Sounds like a [tag:logrotate] problem

Comment: @BroSlow I thoought logrotate can be done only on *.log files.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your FILES variable is wrong. It findes all the files not just the oldest. you could use something like this:

`find /mnt/capture/PPO/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -5 | awk '{print $9}'`

This findes the 5 oldest files in your directory. You can then change that number according to your needs.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me what does 'awk {print $9}' means?

Comment: it prints out the 9th column of the result of the prewious command. if the result would be "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12", awk '{print $9}' would return 9

Comment: In this case the previous command returns a bunch of data, like permissions on the file, owner, creation date, filename and size. And awk cuts off all the nonsense and returns only the filename (which includes the path)